# SwiftUI : custom pop menu in WKWebView

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

In My Swift project, I use a wkWebView to display HTML content retrieved from a webservice. Everything works.
I would like to go further and allow the user to report a fault through the menu when part of the text is selected.

Instead of proposing "copy, cut and paste", I would only like "Copy" + "Report a fault".

The button would have the action of opening the mailbox and inserting the selected text there.

I don't know how to do it. I'm only able to disable the "cut"/"paste" buttons and only keep "copy".

My code :

```
struct articleWebView: UIViewRepresentable  {
    
     ...
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {

        let WKWebView = CustomWKWebView()
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    
          ...
     }
}

class CustomWKWebView: WKWebView {

 //we deactivate everything except "copy" 
 override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        switch action {
        case #selector(copy(_:)):
            return true

        default:
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's been 6 months but here is the answer (works perfectly before iOS 16. With iOS 16 the function is deprecated but still works)

everything happens in canPerformAction

```
class CustomWKWebView: WKWebView{
    


    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

            let menu = UIMenuController.shared
            menu.shared.menuItems = []
            let newInstanceItem = UIMenuItem(title: " My Custom Action", action:#selector(myCustomAction))
            menu.menuItems = [newInstanceItem]
            menu.update()
            if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) || action == #selector(myCustomAction)){

                return true
            }
            return false

    }



    @objc func myCustomAction() {
        // your code

    }

}
```